# Change CakePHP database configuration globally

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I have two databases used for my CakePHP project, respectively named `project` and `project_dev`. The database `project` is used in production and because since the version 3, the CakePHP remove the table prefix option, I choose to use two separated databases.

Extract from my /config/app.php :

```
'Datasources' => [
    'dev' => [...],
    'prod' => [...]
]
```

The problem is that I need to use the `dev` database... for development; so I need to tell Cake to use the `dev` configuration by default during development.

To do that, I tried to create an `AppTable.php`, a class inherited by all my *Table.php files, with the following function :

```
/**
 * Define the connection name based on the debug config value
 * @return string the connection name
 */
public static function defaultConnectionName(): string {
    return Configure::read('debug') ? 'dev' : 'prod';
}
```

The problem for a few tasks, such as unit tests, Cake is trying to use the `default` database config.

I'm afraid that my `AppTable.php` hack is not efficient and I think that tweaking the configuration on load directly in `app.php` like this :

```
$config = [
    [...],
    'Datasources' => [
        'dev' => [...],
        'prod' => [...]
    ],
    'UseDatasourcesConfig' => 'dev',
    [...],
];

$config['Datasources']['default'] = $config['Datasources']['UseDatasourcesConfig'];

return $config;
```

...sounds, like a hack too.

Is this second method viable? Or does a more formal/proper way to set the database config globally exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing configuration depending on the environment is a pretty common task, and there's quite a few other ways to handle this.

### Environment variables

In case the environment allows it, you could use environment variables. You could easily provide DB configuration via the `DATABASE_URL` variable in form of a DSN connection string like

```
mysql://user:pass@localhost/production?encoding=utf8&timezone=UTC&cacheMetadata=true
```

**[Cookbook > Configuration > Environment Variables](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#environment-variables)**

### Additional config files

Another option is to load separate/additional config files based on the current environment, so that you can deploy only those files that are actually required for a specific environment.

```
Configure::load('app', 'default', false);
// $enviroment needs to be validated /sanitzied in order to
// avoid loading arbitrary files from the config directory
Configure::load($enviroment, 'default', true);
```

**[Cookbook > Configuration > Loading Additional Configuration Files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#loading-additional-configuration-files)**

### Connection aliasing

And there's also connection aliasing, CakePHP does that automatically in the test environment. Say you have a `default` and a `production` confiuration, you could then alias the `production` connection as `default` in your production environment, so that everywhere your code tries to use the `default` connection, it will actually use the `production` one.

```
\Cake\DataSource\ConnectionManager::alias('production', 'default');
```

**[API > \Cake\DataSource\ConnectionManager::alias()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionManager.html#_alias)**

Comment: Thank you very much for all those details!