# How do I make CakePHP 3 detect production vs live servers? To disable Debugkit

Tags: cakephp-3.0

What I do is I set debugkit to false in bootstrap.php

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => false]); 
}
```

hen I push that to my live server and gitignore bootstrap.php. Then I enable it to true on my localhost

The problem is if I modify bootstrap.php my changes aren't being  recorded due to gitignore. I know there must be a better way thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43127083/1392379 you might find further answers that handle this topic more broadly if you search for the techniques mentioned there.

Comment: thanks ndm, did search for it but couldn't find it